# How to retrieve one specific document from a collection on cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to retrieve a document from the 'announcements' collection of my document. Each of the documents in the collection is named a day of the year, for example '2020-07-02'. I want to retrieve the document for the current day. In the document, I need to access a map array titled 'details' containing the various announcements. How would I write that into my app? Here is what I am doing currently, but I don't know where to go from there.

```
 Future getAnnouncements() async {
   var currentDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(DateTime.now());
   var firestore = Firestore.instance;
   Stream<DocumentSnapshot> qn = firerestore.collection('announcements').document(currentDate).snapshots();
   return qn; //I want to only return the map array of the various documents
 }
```

Comment: quick question, is the data type of 'details' in firestore a Map or an Array?

Comment: it is an array of maps, each map contains a 'category' which is a string and a 'text' which is also a string

Comment: seems like you'll have to return the data with a datatype of List<Map>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```dart
 Future getAnnouncements() async {
   var currentDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(DateTime.now());
   var firestore = Firestore.instance;
   Future<DocumentSnapshot> qn = await firerestore.collection('announcements')
   .document(currentDate)
   .get();

   return List<Map>.castFrom(qn["details"]);
   
 }
```

To parse through the returned `List`, you could try this

```dart
List<Map> retrievedData = await getAnnouncements();
for(int i = 0; i < retrievedData.length; i++)
{
  print(retrievedData[i]["title"]);
  print(retrievedData[i]["text"]); // Thanks @VLXU
}
```

Comment: how would I access the different elements of the map such as the 'title' and 'text'?

Comment: List<Map> retrievedData = await getAnnouncements();
print(retrievedData[0][“title”]);

Comment: @Abhinav-Bala you could try the soultion in the updated answer

Comment: @ByteMe I tried using this code but I get this error: A value of type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DocumentSnapshot'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'DocumentSnapshot'.

Comment: @Abhinav-Bala my bad, I forgot to include the `await` for  querying firestore and adding the Future for the data type. Just fixed it